# Is there a substring(start, length) function?

Tags: java, string, substring

I am trying to use a similar method to C#'s `string.SubString(int start, int length)`.

But the substring function in Java is `string.substring(int start, int end)`.

I want to be able to pass a start position and a length to the substring function.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: No, but you can easily write one, or modify your code appropriately.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It could be something like

```
String mySubString(String myString, int start, int length) {
    return myString.substring(start, Math.min(start + length, myString.length()));
}
```

Comment: This is nit-picking, but your suggested method is not the same as the C# string.Substring() method. The C# method always returns a string whose length is the specified length, or it fails. Your method is more fault-tolerant, but with the side effect that the returned string may be shorter than the specified length.

Comment: And now for some super-nit-picking: You've made the same mistake as the OP and called the method "SubString" instead of "Substring". :-)

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get is by using the String's [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

```
new String(input.getBytes(),start,length);
```

Comment: downvoted because it doesn't account for characters that encode to more than one byte (UTF-8 being Java's default encoding)

Answer (score -2):

yes

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

public String substring(int beginIndex,
               int endIndex)

you just need to calculate a little in order to get the endIndex.

Comment: so? then he should use it and his head to calculate the desired values. it's not that hard
and he edited his question, i just saw his previous version

Comment: I'm not saying it's hard, I'm saying this is not an answer as you're telling OP what he/she already mentioned in the question. I didn't see the pre-edited question, but answers should be modified to take into account the latest edit.